# I would like to open pgsql query in a new window rather than downloading as csv

Tags: php, html, postgresql

The below code successfully downloads the results of a pgsql query as a csv file on a form submission. However, changing attachment to inline generated a downloaded php file with all the data. My end goal is to open these results in a new window as a table. As a note, this is the second button within the form with a separate php formaction.

```
$result = pg_query_params($conn, $sql, $params);

if (!$result) {
echo "Query failed.\n";
exit;
}
$num_fields = pg_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{
    $headers[] = pg_field_name($result , $i);
}

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result)
{
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        fputcsv($fp, $headers);

        while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
        {
             fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
        }
        die;

}
    exit('It works');
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can't** open a new windows by means of HTTP headers or any other result property, it has to be part of the request.

to get a new window use the `target` attribute on the form or link that makes the request to this form.

eg `<form target="_blank"`... or `<a target="_BLANK"`...

but you'll probably get a new tab instead of a new window.